# OpenGL ES 2.0 on iOS non-square texture gets distorted when rendered

Tags: iphone, ios, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I am working on OpenGL ES 2.0 on iOS and I have this...

1. A texture (T1) with some image (size 1024x768).
2. An off screen FBO (FBO1) associated texture T1 so that I can render something into T1.
3. Another texture (T2) of the same size.
4. Another FBO (FBO2) associated with T2. (I will render to texture T2 with it).

Now in a loop, I render the content of T1 into FBO2 (so T1 gets transferred to T2) and then render T2 into FBO1 (T2 gets transferred back into T1).

After couple of iterations (just 7-8), the original image which was loaded to T1 gets severely distorted/blurred (as if it did a horizontal blur).

But if I do the same thing with a square image (need not be power of two), the image remains clear.

Here is the code that I use to create the texture..

```
GLuint texture = 0;
glGenTextures(1, &texture);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buffer);
```

And here is the code I use to create the FBO...

```
 glGenFramebuffers(1, &targetFBO);
 glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, targetFBO);
 glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture, 0);
```

My shaders are the most basic ones, just renders the texture into gl_FragColor.

Here is my render Objective-C code...

```
- (void) draw {
    GLfloat textureCoordinates[] = {
        0.0f, 0.0f,
        1.0f, 0.0f,
        0.0f,  1.0f,
        1.0f,  1.0f,
    };

    GLfloat imageVertices[] = {
        -1.0f, -1.0f,
        1.0f, -1.0f,
        -1.0f,  1.0f,
        1.0f,  1.0f,
    };

    glViewport(0, 0, targetWidth, targetHeight);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, targetFBO);
    glUseProgram(program);
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE2);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureID);
    glUniform1i(inputTextureLocation, 2);
    glDisable(GL_BLEND);

    glVertexAttribPointer(positionLocation, 2, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0, imageVertices);
    glVertexAttribPointer(inputTextureCoordinateLocation, 2, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0, textureCoordinates);
    // Clear the screen
    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);   
}
```

And my vertex shader...

```
 attribute vec4 position;
 attribute vec4 inputTextureCoordinate;

 varying vec2 textureCoordinate;

 void main()
 {
     gl_Position = position;
     textureCoordinate = inputTextureCoordinate.xy;
 }
```

Fragment shader...

```
 varying highp vec2 textureCoordinate;

 uniform sampler2D inputTexture;

 void main()
 {
     gl_FragColor = texture2D(inputTexture, textureCoordinate);
 }
```

Original image...[image: Original Image]

Distorted image ...[image: Distorted image]

How do I avoid blurring on non-square textures?

**Edit:** The problem is actually with No-Power-of-Two textures. Not just non-square. I am not able to find a solution, so I am going with POT textures.

Comment: How do you "render the content of T1 into FBO2"?

Comment: I have added the code that I use to render to texture FBO. I use this code to draw the texture T1 (or T2) into FBO2 (or FBO1).

Comment: What happens if you use GL_NEAREST instead of GL_LINEAR?

Comment: I'm not sure if that actually makes a difference on the iPhone GPU, but you could try using a high precision sampler with `uniform highp sampler2D inputTexture;`?

Comment: I've noticed the same thing regarding non-power of two (NPOT) textures and I'm wondering if you've found a solution (other than using power of two textures)? I found the problem doing data integrity testing for our GPGPU code. NPOT textures work fine in desktop OpenGL as well as in the iOS Simulator, so I wonder if its a bug? Or perhaps I'm not doing something right?

Comment: Are the sizes of FBOs same as textures? 1024x768?
Did you call glPixelStore with pack/unpack alignments?